# Algorithm to generate hyperbolic metric on a compact surface

Tags: algorithms, hyperbolic-geometry, geometric-group-theory

Let $F$ be a compact surface of genus $g$ with generators $a_1,b_1,\ldots ,a_g,b_g$ with relation $[a_1,b_1]\cdots [a_g,b_g]=1$. We can also consider surfaces with boundary in which case the fundamental group will be a free group.

Now a hyperbolic metric on $F$ corresponds to a discrete faithful representation of $\pi_1(F)$ into $PSL_2(\mathbb{R})$. So the whole problem boils down to finding matrices corresponding to $a_i$ and $b_i$ such that the subgroup generated by them is discrete. My question is:

**Is there any algorithm to generate discrete faithful representations of $\pi_1(F)\,\,\, \mbox{into}\,\,\, PSL_2(\mathbb{R})$?**

I want to check the lengths of certain curves represented as a product of the generators in various hyperbolic metrics. Therefore once I get such algorithm I can write a program to calculate the traces and hence the lengths of those curves.

It would be extremely helpful If anybody knows about any package which already does this.

PS: Please explain the algorithm if possible.

Comment: What do you mean by "a hyperbolic metric on $F$ corresponds to a discrete faithful representation of $\pi_1(F)$ into $PSL_{2}(\mathbb{R})$"? I'm not familiar with this correspondence: does it requires passing to the universal covering of $F$ and acting on it by $\pi_1(F)$?

Comment: @GiovanniMoreno Exactly. Constructing a hyperbolic metric is same as finding subgroups of $PSL_2(R)$ (which is the automorphism  group of the upper half plane $\mathbb{H}$) which acts properly discontinuously on $\mathbb{H}$.

Comment: I can't claim to have used it, but Alden Walker's shine http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~nmd/computop/#shine seems to have some of the functionality you are looking for.

Comment: @Cusp Understood. So, there is a $4g$-sided polygon $P_g$ in $\mathbb{H}$ such that the projection to $F$ is one-to-one in the interior and identifies the sides. By joining in the middle the sides labeled by the same letter, you'll get $2g$ geodesics, and $\pi_1(F)$ should consist of discrete translations along them (I guess), which probably are easily described by the exponential map. I have played a lot with hyperbolic polygons in Wolfram Mathematica and I know there are a lot of packages for this purpose, though it was quicker for me to write simple routines from scratch!

Comment: For 2-generator groups the problem of algorithmically constructing discrete representations to PSL(2,R) is solved in Gilman's book "Two-generator discrete subgroups of PSL(2,R)". The surface group case will obviously be more difficult.